# Android Pass Context in object

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-context, kodein

I need to pass the Application Context to an object. This is to call a function to intercept in the okhttpClient, my connection service. I'am using an object class to build the connection to the server with retrofit and an external interface with my services.

```
object DfreeApiService  {

   private lateinit var interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
   private lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
   private lateinit var networkConnectivityInterceptor: NetworkConnectivityInterceptor

   val client: Retrofit
   get() {
       networkConnectivityInterceptor= NetworkConnectivityInterceptor() //cannot pass the context here
       interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
       interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
       okHttpClient= OkHttpClient.Builder()
          // .addInterceptor(networkConnectivityInterceptor)
           .addInterceptor(interceptor)
           .connectionSpecs(
               Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT)
           )
           .followRedirects(true)
           .followSslRedirects(true)
           .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
           .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .cache(null)
           .build()

           val retrofit: Retrofit =Retrofit.Builder()
               .client(okHttpClient)
               .baseUrl("http://example:2000/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build()

       return retrofit

   }

}
```

And in the following code is my **interface:**

```
interface AuthenticationApi {

    @POST("ws/login")
    suspend fun login(@Body userInfo: UserInfo): Response<UserReponse>

    @POST("ws/register")
    suspend fun register(@Body userInfo: UserRegister): Response<UserReponse>

    @POST("ws/pw_recover")
    suspend fun pw_recover(@Body email: String): Response<BaseResponse>

    @POST("ws/login")
    suspend fun loginGoogle(@Body user: GoogleUser) : Response<UserReponse>


    companion object{
        operator fun invoke():AuthenticationApi{
            return DfreeApiService.client.create(AuthenticationApi::class.java)
        }
    }
  }
```

I'am using mvvm and kodein.
Without the internet interceptor the app crashes when there is no internet.
**My interceptor:**

```
    class NetworkConnectivityInterceptor(
    context: Context
    ) : Interceptor {

    private val applicationContext = context

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!isInternetAvailable())
            throw NoInternetException("Make sure you have an active data connection")
        return chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val connectivityManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Application.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        connectivityManager?.let {
            it.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.apply {
                result = when {
                    hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                    hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                    else -> false
                }

            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Can you post message of raised exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mainActivity:

```
class ExampleApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {
lateinit var context: Context
override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
    import(androidXModule(this@ExampleApplication))
    bind() from singleton { ExampleApiService }
    bind() from singleton { AuthenticationApi() }
    bind() from singleton { NetworkConnectivityInterceptor(instance()) }
    bind() from singleton { ExampleDataBase(instance()) }
    bind<UserRepository>() with singleton { UserRepository(instance(), instance()) }
    bind() from provider { AuthenticationLoginViewModelFactory(instance(),instance()) }
    bind() from provider { CreateAccountViewModelFactory(instance(),instance()) }
    bind() from provider { PasswordViewModelFactory(instance(),instance()) }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DfreeApiService.init(this)
}
```

}

And in the object DfreeApiSercive:

```
object DfreeApiService  {

private lateinit var application: Application

fun init(application: Application){
    this.application=application
}

 private lateinit var interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
private lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
private lateinit var networkConnectivityInterceptor: NetworkConnectivityInterceptor


val client: Retrofit
get() {
    networkConnectivityInterceptor= NetworkConnectivityInterceptor(application.applicationContext)
    interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    okHttpClient= OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(networkConnectivityInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
...
}
}
```

And with this way you can import the context to an object.